# C++: Setting string pointer to const string value

Tags: c++

Basically I'm required to create an Element that holds an id and a key. The private values for id and key are string* and int respectively.

```
Element::Element(const string & id, int key) {
    this->id = id;
    this->key = key;
}
```

When setting this up, I obviously run into issues.

```
cannot convert ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ in assignment
  this->id = id;
```

So I'm wondering how I would set it up so my private member id is equal to the const string & id.

EDIT: To clarify, having these values be a string pointer and const string wasn't my decision. It's just part of the project for reasons I can't fathom.

Comment: Why not change your member variable to `std::string` instead of `std::string*`?

Comment: Having a naked `std::string*` pointer in a class sounds like poor design worth revisiting.

Comment: You should not be using pointers unless you own the resource being pointed at. Be you  I mean the class with the pointer should own the resource being pointed at. Cross object pointers are a very bad idea as you have no idea if/when the object being pointed at has a lifetime that matches your pointer and no way to get that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign `std::string const&` to a variable of `std::string*`.
It's pretty much like trying to save a value in place of pointer.
Possible solutions are:

```
this->id = new std::string(id);
```

It'll make a copy of `id` and store it as a member. But be sure to clean resources afterwards. 
But I cannot recommend this solution. Do you really need to store member as pointer?

If connected string will never be changed (being assigned only once, in constructor) use of reference is better solution:

```
... //member definitions
std::string const& id;
...
```

Then, in constructor you'll need to specify id:

```
...
Element::Element(/*Params*/) : id(id) {
...
```

If it isn't suitable, it's possible to just store member string as value, then you wouldn't need to worry about cleaning up your pointer afterwards.

---

On a quick additional note, it's generally bad practice to use 'raw' pointers. If pointer is absolutely necessary (cannot be replaced with reference or value) it's still better to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` as they will prevent resource leeks.

---

ANSWER TO EDIT:
If you're unable get rid of 'pointer' here, you need to determine whether you need to access changes to the string passed as ID initially. 
If yes, you're better to go with Mateusz Wojtczak's answer with potential pointer problems once initial ID goes out of scope.
If no, just make explicit copy using `new`. Just don't forget to `delete` it in the destructor.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to write your class like this:

```
class Element {
    std::string id; // Should these be const?
    int key;

    public:
    Element(const string &id, int key): id(id), key(key) {}
};
```

Is that all there is in an `Element`? Then you can just write `using Element = std::pair<const std::string, int>`. Or if you are adding Elements to a container such as a `std::vector` or `std::set`, then you can avoid creating a new class and just use a `std::map<const std::string, int>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are assigning reference to pointer. Assign address to pointer, and keep constnes, 'id' should be pointer to const:

```
const std::string* id;
```

and assignment:

```
this->id = &id;
```

This is explanation. Other thing is that this can lead to dangling pointer if object handled is deleted.

Comment: This can end up badly once scope from which `Element` constructor was called gets cleaned and initial `id` variable - destroyed.

Comment: yes you are right, this is only answer to question thou, anyway I can add note.

Comment: Maybe storing string as reference (`std::string const&`) would suit OP as well. Moreover `std::shared_ptr` is always a better option.

Comment: yep, updating that

Answer (score 1):

```
class Element {
private:
    std::string id; // <- not a pointer
    int key;
public:
    Element(const string& Id, int Key) :
        id(Id),
        key(Key)
    {}
};
```